# List of Halachot LiMosheh MiSinai

Tags: halacha, mesorah-tradition, halacha-lemoshe-misinai

Is there a comprehensive list of things in the Talmud that are "halachot limosheh misinai"- laws that were passed down from Moshe through the generations? An example of such is tefilin needing to be square and black.

Comment: Look at Rambam's Introduction to his Commentary on the Mishneh. I think he gives an explanation into that. The Oral Law, even found in the Mishneh, is obviously a compilation of what was originally given at Har Sinai and what was later developed by the Sanhedrin. So you have a legitimate question.

Comment: Are you specifically referring to places where the Talmud uses the phrase הלכה למשה מסיני? What about places where it's clearly not actually from משה?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for things the Talmud lists as הלכה למשה מסיני.

Comment: http://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/31_halachos_lmoshe_misinai_according_to_the_rambam/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Thanks to @Sharshi, this question is answered.*
[31_halachos_lmoshe_misinai_according_to_the_rambam](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/31_halachos_lmoshe_misinai_according_to_the_rambam/)

> In the introduction to his commentary on the Mishna, the Rambam lists 31 halachos l’Moshe miSinai, which he says are most of them, if not all of them. These are:
>
> 1. That the loaves of a thanksgiving offering need a half-log of oil;
> 2. That the offering upon completion of a nazir period requires a quarter-log of oil;
> 3. That there is an eleven-day period of ritual purity between menstrual periods;
> 4. The concept of “gud asik,” legally considering walls to be extended;
> 5. The concept of “lavud,” legally considering small gaps to be closed;
> 6. The concept of “dofen akuma,” that a ceiling is considered the bent extension of a wall;
> 7. Minimum sizes, such as of food for blessings;
> 8. The minimum size of a chatzitzah, an interposition between a person and a mikvah;
> 9. The minimum dimensions of a partition;
> 10. The parchment to be used for tefillin;
> 11. The parchment to be used for mezuzos;
> 12. The parchment to be used for Torah scrolls;
> 13. The shape of the letters Shin on tefillin;
> 14. The shape of the knots of tefillin;
> 15. That the straps of tefillin must be black;
> 16. That tefillin are cube-shaped;
> 17. That tefillin have slits for the straps;
> 18. That tefillin parchments must be rolled and tied with hair from a kosher animals;
> 19. That tefillin compartments must be sewn with thread from kosher animals;
> 20. The ink to use for writing a sefer Torah;
> 21. The quill to use for writing a sefer Torah;
> 22. That a girl violated until the age of three is still legally considered a virgin;
> 23. How to determine how much peah must be given from a field containing several types of grain;
> 24. That the amount of kilayim (diverse species) that may not be plowed if planted accidentally is 1/24 that which would invalidate an entire field;
> 25. That a field with ten or more saplings may be plowed right up until Shemittah;
> 26. That if a food item is partially impure, one may take terumah from the pure portion for both the pure and impure parts;
> 27. That the laws of orlah (the fruit of a tree’s first three years) apply in all places;
> 28. That a teacher may use an oil lamp to find his students’ place in a text on Shabbos;
> 29. That a woman is liable even for carrying in the back of her apron on Shabbos;
> 30. That a wine merchant is permitted to mix strong and weak wines together;
> 31. That Jews who live in Ammon and Moab must give maaser ani (tithe for the poor) every seven years.
>
> Halachos l’Moshe miSinai are typically introduced by the words “b’emes omru” (“in truth, they said”), though the phrase does not necessarily always indicate a halacha l’Moshe miSinai. Furthermore, the phrase “halacha l’Moshe miSinai” is sometimes used to identify laws that are ancient and universally accepted like actual halachos l’Moshe miSinai. Even in the Rambam’s list, at least two of the “halachos l’Moshe miSinai” (28 and 30) appear to refer to rabbinic enactments.

Comment: Good start. But this is explicitly not a comprehensive list, which is what the OP was looking for...

Answer (score 3):

**[R' Yair Bachrach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yair_Bacharach)** (1639-1702) in [Chavot Yair, *teshuva* 192](https://www.sefaria.org/Havot_Yair.192.65?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) gives a much longer list of Halachot L'Moshe MiSinai (61!) and takes issue with the Rambam and the methodology used to create his list.